# Error with CURL requests to enable TOTP in WSO2 IS

Tags: server, wso2, identity, totp

I have a problem using the TOTP admin services in WSO2 IS (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Using+the+TOTP+API#UsingtheTOTPAPI-EnableTOTPEnableTOTP). I send the following request:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46TGF0aW51czAx" https://192.168.0.238:9443/services/TOTPAdminService/resetTOTP -k -d 'username=admin'
```

And get this error:

```
C:\Users\Administrador>curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -H "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46TGF0aW51czAx" https://192.168.0.238:
9443/services/TOTPAdminService/resetTOTP -k -d 'username=admin'
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6BC764F5BB95F534DA74528AF92572BA; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnl
y
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 21:39:56 GMT
Connection: close
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<faultstring>Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method resetTOTP<
/faultstring>
```

TOTP is configured properly because I can enable and disable it manually. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a workaround I found for this was to use SoapUI, adding the wsdl of TOTP (https://localhost:9443/services/TOTPAdminService?wsdl). There you can enable and disable TOTP, and refresh and get the key. Also consider that authorization is needed, it could be basic authorization with user and password. Hope this helps somebody :)